# Vue js and Firestore: get data from Firestore but don't display any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display my data from my Firestore but I hover on my `<td>` tag it shows that it gets the data but it doesn't show it.

**My file to get the data from Firestore**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-btn @click="back" dark>Back</v-btn>
        <h1>apple</h1>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Catogorie</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Product</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="addProducts in Products" :key="addProducts.id">
                        <td>{{addProducts.catogorie}}</td>
                        <td>{{addProducts.product}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
/*eslint-disable-line*/import { db } from '../../Database';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    firestore: {
        Products: db.collection('Products')
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Products: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        back() {
            location.reload();
            console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this.Products)
    }
}
</script>
```

**FireStore**
[image]

On the left side you see the td tags but shows no data. And on the right side I draw a box there you see I have 2 documents in my Firestore. I tried many diffrent things.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot loop over the Documents addProducts property like that.

You need to loop over the products preferably with this naming to not cause confusion:

`v-for="product in Products"`

And then you can access every property of the `addProducts` map through `product.addProducts.catogorie` etc.

Comment: I tried that but I got this error message: `Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: @Mustafa did you make it the right casing? Products not products ?

Comment: Ow yeah sry my bad I didn't see that. Now it works. Thanks for your help Badgy.